# Fourier Transform of char. function of $d$-dimensional unit cube

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I want to find the Fourier transform of the unit cube.
So far, I have
$$f(\xi) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac d 2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\chi_{[-1,1]^d}e^{-i\langle x,\xi\rangle}dx = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac d 2}\int_{[-1,1]^d}e^{-i\langle x,\xi\rangle}dx$$
Now I don't know how to continue with that dot product in the exponent, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $\langle x,\xi\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^d x_n\xi_n$ we have

$$\int_{[-1,1]^d}e^{-i\langle x,\xi\rangle}\,dx=\prod_{n=1}^d \int_{-1}^1 e^{-ix_n\xi_n}\,dx_n$$

And now you can finish.

Comment: Why are we allowed to pull the product out of the integral? 0.0

Comment: Recall that $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$.  And this leads to separation of the iterated integrals.

Comment: For completeness sake: This works because of Fubinis theorem. (That was the missing mental link :))